# font awesome not showing in firefox using hubspot

Tags: font-awesome, hubspot

I am using hubspot and followed all the directions on to upload the fonts into hubspot for my site.  but in firefox and chrome the icons will not show up.  I get a box in chrome and in firefox I get a box with f098 or something like that.

Answer (score 0):

> when you give the uploaded font links make the http:// to https:// 
>   or check
>   the firebug console error list